# Apache configuration for ReactJS with React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, apache, debian, apache2, react-router-v4

I do have an application build with ReactJS and React Router V4 that I'm trying to release to production.

At production I have Apache with the following configuration:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SetEnv APP_HOME /usr/local/bin/myapp
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
    # Don't rewrite files or subdirectories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

On browse, I do:

```
http://192.168.0.100
```

it loads my landing page. But from there I cannot access any other url:

```
http://192.168.0.100/login
http://192.168.0.100/status
http://192.168.0.100/detail/1
http://192.168.0.100/dashboard
```

All pages I get the following error from Apache:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /status was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at 192.168.0.100 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I'm pretty sure something is wrong with my configuration (may be my RewriteCond/RewriteRule), but no idea on how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year late, but I wanted to share this solution, assuming Ubuntu OS is used, in case anyone has the same concern as you did:

I've followed certain steps from this [post from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4e6lbt/getting_react_routing_to_work_with_apache2) and I can attest this works for making SPAs run in Apache web server with proper routing.

To quote:

1) In the `apache2.conf` located in `etc/apache2/` I turned `AllowOverride` to `All`. I also added Servername localhost in the file. (I somehow skipped this last sentence, but still it worked fine in the end)

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

2) In the `hosts.debian.tmpl` file found in `/etc/cloud/templates` I added `127.0.0.1 <yourdomain.com>` to the file where the other ips of the similiarity are.

```
127.0.0.1 yourdomain.com
```

3) I ran `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. Then I restarted the apache server via `service apache2 restart`. This turns on mod_rewrite.

Lastly inside of my project folder `/var/www/html` , along side my `index.html` file I created a `.htaccess` file and added in the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,QSA]
```

End quote

Assuming you've run `npm run build` and then copied all the contents inside the `build` folder to your public directory, this should work.

When I first started web dev, I wasn't really sure I made the VirtualHost config right, so what I usually did was first to make a dummy index.html with, say, Hello World example. When I've confirmed that I'm able to see Hello World in the browser (which means I got the VirtualHost config right), I dump the contents of the `build` folder to where the dummy index.html was.

Hope this helps you now as much as it did for me!